# Choose a specific manager for a related field for a model

Tags: django

I am in a situation where I need to use a custom manager for a related field which is different from the base_manager for the related fields. Let's say that I have a model `Item` which is in one to many relation with another model `Purchase`. Now, `Item` has 2 managers:

```py
objects = ItemManager() #which by default excludes the out_of_stock=True items
complete = CompleteItemManager() #which gives all the items.
```

For all the other models related to `Item`, `ItemManager` is the default one. But in `Purchase`, I would want to use the `CompleteItemManager` for the related Item.

So let's say there was once a purchase for an item which is now has `out_of_stock=True` and we just have the id of that purchase say `old_purchase_id`, now if try to run the below query:

```py
purchase = Purchase.objects.filter(id=old_purchase_id) # gives error
```

It would give an error like `"Item matching query does not exist"` as the manager being used for the related items is ItemManager which excludes such out of stock items.

What can be done in that case? Ideally I would want something to override the manager to be used for a given related field per model, so that even if all other models use `ItemManager` to resolve item fields, the `Purchase` Model still uses the `CompleteItemManager` for its relations with `Item`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I did it.

I made a `CustomForwardManyToOneDescriptor` which would just pick the manager named `complete` for the related model. And used that descriptor in a `CustomForeignKey` as the `forward_related_accessor_class`.

```
class CustomForwardManyToOneDescriptor(ForwardManyToOneDescriptor):
    def get_queryset(self, **hints):
        related_model = self.field.remote_field.model

        return related_model.complete.db_manager(hints=hints).all()


class CustomForeignKey(models.ForeignKey):
    forward_related_accessor_class = CustomForwardManyToOneDescriptor
```

Now using the `CustomForeignKey` instead of `ForeignKey` to create OneToMany relation with a model would make that model use the complete manager for the foreign key field no matter what the default related manager is.

Answer (score 2):

When accessing a reverse relation you can specify a custom manager to use by calling the related_name and passing the custom manager by name

```
purchase.item_set.all() # Uses ItemManager
purchase.item_set(manager='complete').all() # Uses CompleteItemManager
```

Comment: The relationship here is one (item) to many (purchase). So `purchase` doesn't have an `item_set` but just `item`. Also, we just have the id for that purchase, not the purchase object and trying to get that gives error as mentioned.

Comment: You get the error accessing `product.item`? Have you overridden `Meta.base_manager_name` in `Item` or `Item._base_manager` then?

Comment: Yes, it gives error. And yes its overriden to use ItemManager for everything else. But for Purchase model, I want to use the CompleteItemManager

Comment: Why override the base manager? The whole point of the _base_manager is to look up items that may otherwise be hidden by custom managers. Is setting the _default_manager not enough? Do you want this error to occur when you access a deleted Item from one of the other ForeignKeys?

Comment: No, I want to use the ItemManager for all the relations except when using Product, where I want the relations to be resolved using CompleteItemManager. That's the question.